# how do I optimize this sql:select count(*) from `order` where `time`>1307894400000

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get orders count for a day(field "time" is java timestamp,and table "order" has **1,000,000 records**), I using:

```
select count(*) from `order` where `time`>1307894400000 && `time`<1307980799999
```

this sql used **540ms**

I tried create index use field "time" ,but still need to **390ms**

how do I optimize this sql statement?

Comment: How many rows are in db and how many are selected?

Comment: see what explain select count(*) from `order` where `time`>1307894400000 && `time`<1307980799999
 outpot

Comment: You've already got an index on the `time` column. That's the most important thing. If you changed `count(*)` to `count(name-of-your-primary-key-column)` you might see a miniscule improvement (unless the query optimizer is now smart enough to do this optimization on its own). Other than that, this is maybe the best you can do.

Comment: I was just reading about count(colname) and according to [this guy](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/20/a-common-problem-when-optimizing-count/) it doesn't do the same thing if null values are involved.  I also wonder if maybe the distribution of the values for the time column aren't spread out very well, causing the optimizer to just ignore it and do a table scan.

Comment: @Marvo: `count(name-of-your-primary-key-column)` avoids the `null` values issue because you can't have a null value in a primary key column.

Comment: How many results is this query returning?  Does making the `time` index the clustered index help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is still not enough then your only choice is [partitioning](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Partition_%28database%29) the table. Many db engines allow specifying automatic partitions.

Comment: I don't see how partitioning would change this query.

Comment: If you partition on ranges of the time column, you'd end up with partitioned tables holding each a fraction of the 1000000 records. Let's say you partition in 10 tables, you'd end up roughly with 100000 records per table. This way the queries will run on smaller tables, and this *should* bring down the query time.

Comment: @Billy, see for example the bullet points at the end of this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-range.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with below.

select count(YourPrimaryKey) from `order` where `time`>1307894400000 && `time`<1307980799999

Comment: I tried, count (id) and count (*) is the same ("id" is primary key)